# SQL Set Value of a Column Using COUNT(*)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to set a column to a specific value of `1/COUNT(*)` in an SQL table. I am wondering how to do this.

To make it clearer, consider the following example. We have a table `table1`

```
TABLE1:
    A  |  B  |  C  
---------------------
    1  |  9  |  0
    2  |  7  |  0
    4  |  8  |  0
    3  |  6  |  0
```

I want to set the column `C` with value of `1/COUNT(*)`, in this case, is `0.25`. So the result should be:

```
TABLE1:
    A  |  B  |  C  
---------------------
    1  |  9  |  0.25
    2  |  7  |  0.25
    4  |  8  |  0.25
    3  |  6  |  0.25
```

However, I tried the following code:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET C = 1/COUNT(*)
```

It does not work and gives me an error:

```
Error: ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in UPDATE
Position: 21
```

How am I supposed to do this in SQL?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an `update`, use a `from` clause:

```
UPDATE TABLE
    SET C = 1.0 / c.cnt
    FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM yourtable ) c;
```

There is no reason to have a separate column.  You can easily calculate this on the fly:

```
select t.*,
       1.0 / count(*) over ()
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Answer:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET C = 1.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE)
```

Comment: please consider to add comment on your post. Try to answer these questions: How did you solve it?  why this is the solution?

Comment: Sometimes coders are in a hurry, here he provided just the answer.